# spark convert dataframe to dataset using case class with option fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have the following case class:

```
case class Person(name: String, lastname: Option[String] = None, age: BigInt) {}
```

And the following json:

```
{ "name": "bemjamin", "age" : 1 }
```

When I try to transform my dataframe into a dataset:

```
spark.read.json("example.json")
  .as[Person].show()
```

It shows me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   cannot resolve '`lastname`' given input columns: [age, name];

My question is: If my schema is my case class and it defines that the lastname is optional, shouldn't the as() do the conversion?

I can easily fix this using a .map but I would like to know if there is another cleaner alternative to this.

Comment: Hi, If you add another json (record 2) with lastname in it, If it works, then I think it infers the schema to three columns. With your example of only one record, how does spark( or anyone) know that you are intending to have 3 columns?

Comment: @Bemjamin Can you please let me know how you would have solve it by using map ? I am trying to solve this for nested json using the answer provided but it does not work so just wanted to have some clue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have one more option to solve above issue.There are 2 steps required

1. Make sure that fields that can be missing are declared as nullable
   Scala types(like Option[_]).
2. Provide a schema argument and not depend on schema inference.You can use for example use **Spark SQL Encoder**:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

   val schema = Encoders.product[Person].schema
   ```

You can update code as below.

```
val schema = Encoders.product[Person].schema

val df = spark.read
           .schema(schema)
           .json("/Users/../Desktop/example.json")
           .as[Person]

+--------+--------+---+
|    name|lastname|age|
+--------+--------+---+
|bemjamin|    null|  1|
+--------+--------+---+
```

Comment: can we do something similar for the nested json ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are performing `spark.read.json("example.json").as[Person].show()`, it is basically  reading the dataframe as ,

```
FileScan json [age#6L,name#7]
```

and then trying to apply the Encoders for Person object hence getting the AnalysisException as it is not able to find `lastname` from your json file.

Either you could hint spark that lastname is optional by supplying some data that has lastname or
try this:

```
val schema: StructType = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Person].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
val x = spark.read
      .schema(schema)
      .json("src/main/resources/json/x.json")
      .as[Person]
+--------+--------+---+
|    name|lastname|age|
+--------+--------+---+
|bemjamin|    null|  1|
+--------+--------+---+
```

Hope it helps.