# Using Spark converting nested json with optional fields to Scala case class not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, case-class, nested-json

I have a use case where I need to read a json file or json string using spark as Dataset[T] in scala. The json file has nested elements and some of the elements in the json are optional. I am able to read the json file and map those to case class if I ignore optional fields in the json as the schema matches with the case class.

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55114210/spark-convert-dataframe-to-dataset-using-case-class-with-option-fields) and answer it works for first level json when case class have option field but if it is there is nested element it does not work.

Json String that I am using is as below :

```
val jsonString = """{
  "Input" :
    {
      "field1" : "Test1",
      "field2" : "Test2",
      "field3Array" : [
      {
      "key1" : "Key123",
      "key2" : ["keyxyz","keyAbc"]
      }
                ]
    },
  "Output": 
    {
      "field1" : "Test2",
      "field2" : "Test3",
      "requiredKey" : "RequiredKeyValue",
      "field3Array" : [
      {
      "key1" : "Key123",
      "key2" : ["keyxyz","keyAbc"]
      }
                ]
    }
}"""
```

The case class that I have created are as below :

```
case class InternalFields (key1: String, key2 : Array[String])
case class Input(field1:String, field2: String,field3Array : Array[InternalFields])
case class Output(field1:String, field2: String,requiredKey : String,field3Array : Array[InternalFields])
case class ExternalObject(input : Input, output : Output)
```

The code through which I am reading the jsonString is as below :

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(Seq(jsonString).toDS).as[ExternalObject]
```

The above code works perfectly fine. Now when I add a optional field in the Output case class as json string could have it to support some use case it throws an error saying that the optional field that I have specified in the case class is missing.

So in order to get around this I went ahead and tried providing schema using encoders and see if that works.

After adding optional field my case class got changed to as below :

```
case class InternalFields (key1: String, key2 : Array[String])
case class Input(field1:String, field2: String,field3Array : Array[InternalFields])
case class Output(field1:String, field2: String,requiredKey : String, optionalKey : Option[String],field3Array : Array[InternalFields])  //changed
case class ExternalObject(input : Input, output : Output)
```

There is one additional optional field added in Output case class.

Now I am trying to read the jsonString as below :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.product[ExternalObject].schema
val df = spark.read
           .schema(schema)
           .json(Seq(jsonString).toDS)
           .as[ExternalObject]
```

When I do df.show or display(df) it gives me output table as below which is null for both input column as well as output column.

[image]

If I remove that optional field from the case class then this code also works fine and shows me the expected output.

Is there any way by which I can make this optional field in the inner json or inner case class work and cast it directly to respective case class inside dataset[T].

Any ideas, guidance, suggestions that can make it work would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that spark uses struct types to map a class to a `Row`, take this as an example:

```
case class MyRow(a: String, b: String, c: Option[String])
```

Can spark create a dataframe, which sometimes has column `c` and sometimes not? like:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  a  |  b  |  c  |
+-----+-----+-----+
| a1  | b1  |  c1 |
+-----+-----+-----+
| a2  | b2  |        <-- note the non-existence here :)
+-----+-----+-----+
| a3  | b3  | c3  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Well it cannot, and being nullable, means the key has to exist, but the value can be null:

```
    ... other key values
    "optionalKey": null,
    ...
```

This is considered to be valid, and is convertible to your structs. I suggest you use a dedicated JSON library (as you know there are many of them out there), and use udf's or something to extract what you need from json.

Comment: if you see the link that I have added in the question has answer that does that but at the root level only. So just wanted to know if there is a way for doing it in nested json.

Answer (score -1):

I tested the above code base with the following case class structres

```
case class Field3Array(
  key1: String,
  key2: List[String]
)
case class Input(
  field1: String,
  field2: String,
  field3Array: List[Field3Array]
)
case class Output(
  field1: String,
  field2: String,
  requiredKey: String,
  field3Array: List[Field3Array]
)
case class Root(
  Input: Input,
  Output: Output
)
```

The Json string cannot be directly passed to the DataFrameReader as you have tried since the `json` method expects a path.
I put the JSON string in a file and passed the file path to the DataFrameReader and the results were as follows

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder,Encoders}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

case class Field3Array(
  key1: String,
  key2: List[String]
)
case class Input(
  field1: String,
  field2: String,
  field3Array: List[Field3Array]
)
case class Output(
  field1: String,
  field2: String,
  requiredKey: String,
  field3Array: List[Field3Array]
)
case class Root(
  Input: Input,
  Output: Output
)


val pathToJson: String = "file:////path/to/json/file/on/local/filesystem"

val jsEncoder: Encoder[Root] = Encoders.product[Root]

val df: Dataset[Root] = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(pathToJson).as[Root]
```

The results for show are as follows:

```
df.show(false)

+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|Input                                       |Output                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|[Test1, Test2, [[Key123, [keyxyz, keyAbc]]]]|[Test2, Test3, [[Key123, [keyxyz, keyAbc]]], RequiredKeyValue]|
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+

df.select("Input.field1").show()

+------+
|field1|
+------+
| Test1|
+------+
```

Comment: your case class don't have any optional fields. My question is related to optional fields only otherwise it works fine..

Comment: You can have optional fields in case classes. For the Output key in your JSON, you can set the type to Option[String] and the json would still be parsed.

Comment: that is what is not working as mentioned in the question...